# Implement well scalable MMORPG with Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, scalability

Is Scala a good choice to implement a well scalable MMORPG? I read about people suggesting Erlang, because better concurrency handling. But Scala has actors/message driven concurrency and functional programming. Should not that handle the concurrency and scaling also well?

Sorry I don't know Erlang and also don't have experience with Scala neither MMORPG development. That's why I can't make the question more concrete yet. I'm looking for the best way to go to develop an easily scalable MMORPG. And think Scala maybe is/could be a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala is fine for a MMORPG, but it doesn't necessarily have existing frameworks that are available for other platforms (especially C++).  Erlang's fault-tolerance and scalability are legendary, but if you use the Akka framework you'll have a comparable set of capabilities (for the most part).

One advantage to using Scala is that you can take advantage of Project Darkstar, a Java-based platform for MMORPG creation.  [Here's an example](http://hvilela.com/java-mmo-game-engine-using-darkstar-and-jmonkey/) of it being used, though I'm not sure it's actively maintained any more.

Comment: This is a bit out of topic, but it sounds like it would be better to use Erlang directly. I know advantages of Scala are all the Java libraries and stuff are available and more developers than for Erlang, but if I want to make everything from scratch with a small team, wanting to learn new things, why use Scala instead of Erlang?

Comment: @Ixx - If you want to make _absolutely everything_ from scratch, the only real reason, aside from aesthetic preference, is that Scala allows you to write higher-performance lower-level code.  (Erlang makes up for that with higher-performance message passing in an application where passing messages is more work than the computations based upon them.)  But as soon as you decide you _don't_ want to write everything from scratch, having all Java libraries available is a big win.

Answer (score 3):

Scala actors (consider [akka](/questions/tagged/akka)) are actually influenced by [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang). This is highly subjective, but I believe actor model is a great fit for [mmorpg](/questions/tagged/mmorpg).

I guess the overall architecture would involve actor per character/NPC - Akka is perfectly capable of handling millions of actors in a cluster. Oh, did I mention Akka 2.0 can be easily distributed?